# How to handle normal and background silent push notification?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to implement the silent push notification for my background fetch.
Now i am facing an issue while implementing the necessary code  in my AppDelegate.

Before i had the following function in order to handle the push notification:

```
-(void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    NSLog(@"Just Received a push!");
...
}
```

I added mow the below function to handle the background fetch silent notification:

```
//backgroundDownloadTask
- (void) application:(UIApplication *)application
  didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
        fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
    NSLog(@"Just Received a push!");
   ....
}
```

The weird thing is that when i receive a normal notification, it also entered the second function and the first one (old) is seems top be useless now, so I added the following to differenciate between the normal and silent one:

```
    //backgroundDownloadTask
    - (void) application:(UIApplication *)application
      didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
            fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
    {
        NSLog(@"Just Received a push!");
        NSDictionary *dict = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];

        if([dict objectForKey:@"content-available"])
        {
//silent
        }
      else
       {
//normal push
       }
}
```

but the issue is when i am in the foreground and I receive a push, No function is executing as no push is received(Maybe because the second function is just for background).

So how am I able to handle both pushes? any idea ?
Thank you,

Comment: Are you sure the first function isn't called when your app is in the foreground? According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH102-SW1) "If your app is frontmost when a user notification arrives, the `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` or `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` method is called on its app delegate"

Comment: the second one - (void) application:(UIApplication *)application
  didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
        fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler is called when i receive a push even when i am  in the foreground.

Comment: didReceiveRemoteNotification will be called in both Silent and Normal pushes